Возникает ошибка Host unreachable при попытке подключения к домашнему серверу по ssh
Очень бесит, пытаюсь подключиться по ssh к ноутбуку в той же сети но возникает ошибка java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
Failed to create connection:
aisulu@192.168.0.13.
Я пробовала ssh/sftp и ftp но все одинаково. Сначала думала что это ftp на телефоне плохой но termux тоже не выдает нужного результата.
Я использовала vsftpd, proftpd и openssh и первые часа 4 после включения все работают но потом ошибка хотя я в настройках отключила ограничения питания, не трогала конфиги и вообще использую только gradle, nodejs и apache.
P.s. Только reboot/poweroff-включить и shutdown now работают для исправления

А сам хост в моменты недоступности пингуется? Если да, то может ssh сервер умирает?
